# EF 4.4: Model changes not syncing with the database

Tags: c#, .net, entity-framework

I added two columns to my model in Entity Framework and changed one field from a string to an Enumeration. When I go to Package Manager Console and type in "update-database," I get the following error:

```
System.Runtime.Serialization.SerializationException: Type is not resolved for member 'System.Data.Entity.Migrations.Design.ToolingFacade+UpdateRunner,EntityFramework, Version=4.4.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=b77a5c561934e089'.
   at System.AppDomain.DoCallBack(CrossAppDomainDelegate callBackDelegate)
   at System.Data.Entity.Migrations.Design.ToolingFacade.Run(BaseRunner runner)
   at System.Data.Entity.Migrations.Design.ToolingFacade.Update(String targetMigration, Boolean force)
   at System.Data.Entity.Migrations.UpdateDatabaseCommand.<>c__DisplayClass2.<.ctor>b__0()
   at System.Data.Entity.Migrations.MigrationsDomainCommand.Execute(Action command)
Type is not resolved for member 'System.Data.Entity.Migrations.Design.ToolingFacade+UpdateRunner,EntityFramework, Version=4.4.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=b77a5c561934e089'.
```

I get the same error for enable-migrations.

I saw that one question recommended getting rid of the __Migrations table, which I did, but it didn't seem to help.

Another solution recommended changing the project to .NET 4.5, and then reinstalling EF 5, which I did, but all that did was change the EF version number in the error.

Any ideas?

Comment: How is ef installed, NuGet? Or file ref?

Comment: I used NuGet to install EF.

Comment: Try enable-migrations-Force in the pm console

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Fixed this issue; had to remove an ampersand from the file path (!!!!)

Comment: What a crazy bug this is. This is the second time one of our team's developers stumbles across your answer here, because we've created a branch with an ampersand in it's name...

Answer (score 0):

I had this same issue and it turned out to be caused by two projects in the solution using different versions of EntityFramework.  My code first objects were built in their own .NET Framework 4.0 assembly, but the startup project of the solution was a .NET 4.5 MVC project. Even though both projects used Entity Framework "5.0", the .NET 4 version of EF5 is a different assembly (version 4.4).

I found that a temporary fix that allowed an "Update-Database" command to work was to change this section in the Web.config file:

```
  <dependentAssembly>
    <assemblyIdentity name="EntityFramework" publicKeyToken="b77a5c561934e089" culture="neutral"/>
    <bindingRedirect oldVersion="0.0.0.0-5.0.0.0" newVersion="5.0.0.0"/>
  </dependentAssembly>
```

To this:

```
  <dependentAssembly>
    <assemblyIdentity name="EntityFramework" publicKeyToken="b77a5c561934e089" culture="neutral"/>
    <bindingRedirect oldVersion="0.0.0.0-4.4.0.0" newVersion="4.4.0.0"/>
  </dependentAssembly>
```

My ultimate fix was to update the assembly with my code first classes to .NET 4.5 and reinstall EF5.